# How do I insert a cookie data value into a hidden form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I would like to be able to take data stored in a cookie and insert it into a hidden form value.

I am storing the data in a cookie using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnCookie").bind("click", function () {
            $.cookie("name", $("#txtName").val());
```

I am able to retrieve the value as plain text on the next page using:

```
$.cookie("name")
```

I have a form on the 2nd page that I want this value to be a part of. How can I insert it into the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cookie" />
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cookie" value="$.cookie("name")" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
var cookie_val = $.cookie("name");
$('input[name=cookie]').val(cookie_val);
```

Answer (score 2):

`<input type="hidden" name="cookie" value="$.cookie('name')" />`

The double quotes are causing an error in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery cookie u can use in php.

```
value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['name']; ?>"
or use jquery
$('input[name=cookie]').val($.cookie("name"));
```